# Why can't I find my app on the Android Market with a 240 X 320 phone?

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

I have read many posts at here. I have set the minSdkVersion to "4" and smallScreens to "true". But it still doesn't work on my IDEOS Android phone (Android 2.2).

I set the Copy Protection to "On". Have I done anything wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml or I need to make change to my code also?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

---

I have changed my Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />-->


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

But I still cannot find my app on Android Market with small screen device.

Can anyone using small screen device find my app on Android Market? My app is called **nanonavi**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of phone features listed in the manifest. If your phone does not have every one of them, it won't show up because the market will think that the app won't work on your phone.

If you want your app to use a feature if it's there, but will operate correctly without it, then test for it at run time but don't list it in the manifest.

Comment: But I can install and run the app with the .apk file. Does it mean my phone supports all features in the manifest?

Comment: @Peter - I'd recommend removing all the <uses-feature> tags if the app behaves correctly without them. They are used as market filters. See the docs for more details about [market filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html).